# how to delete queue for larger size?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I need to delete queue which consist 10,000 elements drawing on the screen. I want to delete them after some time and update with new queue. I'm able to do that, but I can see it's not quickly deleting the elements. It takes a second without any updates on the and deletes them. This is what I'm doing to delete them:

```
    std::queue<Particle> empty;
    // created a empty queue

    std::swap(buff,empty); 
    //swapped it to buff in the function I'm using for update
```

I can see it takes so much time on swapping. Is there any other efficient way to clear the queue?

Comment: Try redefining the queue: `buff = queue<Particle>();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `buff.swap(empty)` see here for more reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/swap/

Comment: It's giving the same result as swap(buff,empty). Is this is the only effective way to delete queue?

Comment: Are you sure its slowing down here? 10k element isn't a lot for particles, your slowness might be somewhere else